# Add an icon on a question

Tags: support, feature-request, status-declined

I would like to personalize more my questions adding check marks, icons, emojis:

> :D --emojis happy-face.

It is possible and how can I do that?

For example, if I want to expensify the close icon: 
when I click the **X** an error happen.

Comment: We don't want personalizations.  We want questions and answers.  All the other stuff you're mentioning will only get in the way, and thus make it more difficult for us to help you.

Comment: No, there are no tiers, and there will never be.

Comment: We are a no nonsense Q&A site priding itself on a low noise ratio.... i feel like adding this would be a great step in the completely wrong direction

Comment: The appearance of test details, inputs/outputs, error-messages and details of debugging done are sufficient to evoke happy thoughts.   A smiley-face with a code/requirement dump makes me want to hack up the face with a machete.

Comment: There is a huge difference between using icons in general (which can be *sometimes* useful, when used properly and **as a helper (not as the main thing)**) and "personalization" - **which is a VERY bad idea to do here and would destroy this network.**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For relevant UI elements, we have screenshots. A single check mark or button is not going to contribute anything.

For relevant HTML, we have snippets (including buttons and checkmarks).

If relevant (and rarely relevant), we do have unicode support, and that includes many emoji's (but note that support might vary between browsers and operating systems).

I don't see a use case for check marks or emoji's. Proper use is less likely than misuse in my opinion.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I would argue against that; I prefer your answer since it does not even _suggest_ that emoji can be used as yivi's does: _"I guess you could insert emojis in the title of your question directly"_. The ironic/meta thumbs down also does not really help the case for yivi's answer. The distinction between the answers is small, but (I think) worth preserving.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Thanks for your opinion. As at least two people agree with you, I guess it can't hurt. Removed the comment, won't delete.

Answer (score 8):

to that idea.

It is not possible nor desired. Content should speak for itself. No need for emojis.

I guess you *could* insert emojis in the title of your question directly, but I would advise you **not** to do it, and expect those characters to be edited out if you do insert them. And consider that emoji support varies a lot depending on the platform, so better not to rely on those to convey your meaning.

You can use emoji characters if they are relevant to your question (e.g. encoding or rendering problems).

But if you need to use actual examples of UI elements, just use screenshots. SO does have support for inserting images into your questions.

Comment: what about check marks or icons like buttons.

Comment: @Jesse Just try to be as professional as possible and let the content do the talking. Do not think of SO as a regular forum or social network, because it is not one of those things.